# MySQL join and column names

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Let's say that I have the following tables in my MySQL database:

```
TABLE Products
| id | some_column1 | some_column2 |

TABLE ProductProperties
| id | product_id | name |
```

Oversimplified, but sufficient. Now I want to get all products with properties. I do:

```
SELECT * FROM `Products` JOIN `ProductProperties` ON Products.id = ProductProperties.product_id
```

What do I get?

```
| id | some_column1 | some_column2 | id | product_id | name |
```

It's not cool, and I want to make it cool in one of the two ways:

1) To get the array of objects like in Product table, but extended by one more member, which would be the array of properties which matched JOIN. I've sort of figured out already that it's impossible?

2) To get the array like this (I'd still have to iterate over it in PHP to join all properties in one product into one object):

```
| product_id | some_column1 | some_column2 | property_id | product_id | name |
```

So I'd like to rename the column ProductProperties.id into ProductProperties.property_id. If I could remove ProductProperties.product_id from the output too, that would be ideal, but for now, I only want the way to rename one column in the output. Or to prefix it by table name. Or something like that.

Doable?

Comment: Can you provide test data and desired result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should explicitly name the columns and not use `*`.  Then, don't return redundant columns:

```
SELECT p.id as productid, p.some_column1, p.some_column2,
       pp.id  as ProductPropertiesId, pp.name
FROM `Products` p JOIN `ProductProperties` pp
    ON p.id = pp.product_id
```

Also, table aliases make such a query more readable.

Comment: Hah, that easy. I admit, I don't know SQL, I'm using it only when I must. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @AlW . . . Your question seemed like it was coming from someone without much experience.  Unfortunately, I think, people tend to downvote such questions automatically, instead of appreciating that there is a learning curve involved.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Products.id product_id,
       Products.some_column1,
       Products.some_column2,
       ProductProperties.id property_id,
       ProductProperties.name
FROM `Products` 
JOIN `ProductProperties` 
ON Products.id = ProductProperties.product_id
```